# Parameter simplification of ARIMA model

Tags: regression, time-series, estimation, arima, parameterization

I am constructing an ARIMA model on a cryptocurrency price time series. Using the autocorrelation and partial autocorrelation plots I came to the parameters of (p,d,q)=(3,1,2).
The resulting RMSE was 0.651

In order to see if there would be any better parameters I ran a grid search which resulted in  (p,d,q)=(0,1,1) which gave an identical RMSE of 0.651.

The results of the grid search didn't include (skipped over) the model I had come to of (3,1,2) despite being within the defined ranges.

Is this because the two models are the same but that 0,1,1 is a simplified version of 3,1,2?

Answer (score 1):

I wonder how you used (P)ACF plots to identify an ARIMA(3,1,2) model, because [you can't use them if both $p$ and $q$ are nonzero](https://otexts.com/fpp2/non-seasonal-arima.html).

That said, an ARIMA(0,1,1) is *much* simpler than ARIMA(3,1,2). And no, they are not simply the same model in two different forms. For one, the first one has four parameters less, so its estimation will be far more precise.

I personally would always trust an ARIMA(0,1,1) more than an ARIMA(3,1,2). And I would also trust an order selection based on information criteria, as implemented in `forecast::auto.arima()` for R, more than a Box-Jenkins approach based on (P)ACF plots.